# How to allow a project in the same GCP organization to consume a GCP Vertex AI endpoint?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, api, authentication, organization, iam

A Vertex AI endpoint has been created in the Google Cloud Platform (GCP) project *orgA-projA*.

As a devops I want to authorize another project *orgA-projB* to consume it. The GCP project *orgA-projB* is in the same organization as *orgA-projA*.

What is the best way to do it ?

Comment: Part 1: When posting questions, do not ask for the `best way` as that will solicit opinions. Instead show what your tried and the problem you have including error messages. I have read your other posts and I understand that you are trying to create self-answered questions, but I would first read the guides on how to create questions on StackExchange DevOps [link](https://devops.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Part 2: In Google Cloud, Authentication and Authorization are complicated topics. I have written hundreds of answers on these items on StackOverflow. I would read the posts for the tag [google-cloud-iam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-iam) first. There are many ways to authorize an application. Which method to use depends on details of the application and where it is deployed. There is no `one answer` or even a `best answer` for this topic. Details are required to generate a correct answer.

Comment: I do not want to dissuade your from your goal, but to help you with useful information.